Pandas - FutureWarning in concat - how to fix or opt into new behavior
I have code like the following where I split up a dataframe into different groups. The "treatment" group is where I might want to delete rows and/or modify rows; and for performance reasons I split it into away from a group of rows that should survive unchanged.
It is guaranteed that all DFs have the same columns and dtypes (they all come from the original df parameter).
At the end of the treatment, I want to concat them back to a single DF. Now, I do not know in advance if any of the DFs will be empty. (and if df is empty, all DFs will be empty (happens especially in testing) - usually though df has ~500k rows).
See code:
def some_fn(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df_no_treatment, df_treatment = split_df(df)
    df_treatment = do_something_complex(df_treatment)

    assert (df.dtypes == df_treatment.dtypes).all()
    assert (df.dtypes == df_no_treatment.dtypes).all()

    result = pd.concat([df_no_treatment, df_treatment]).sort_index()

    assert (df.dtypes == result.dtypes).all()
    return result

Now, concat throws a FutureWarning: The behavior of array concatenation with empty entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer exclude empty items when determining the result dtype. To retain the old behavior, exclude the empty entries before the concat operation.
Note the asserts in the code above, it seems to work as intended?
How do I fix the warning or opt into the new behavior? I don't want any automatics with dtypes, they do match and concat should just concat and do not do anything else.
I find code like
    if df_no_treatment.empty:
        return df_treatment
    if df_treatment.empty:
        return df_no_treatment
    return pd.concat([df_no_treatment, df_treatment]).sort_index()

absolutely over the top for what was previously a simple concat. What am I missing?

pd.concat([df for df in (df_no_treatment, df_treatment) if not df.empty]) would be rather simple.

No, that does not work if both dfs are empty. You would essentially concat([]) in that case and get an error No objects to concatenate

Which is a logic error, isn't it?

Why would that be a logic error? An empty DF with columns A:float and B:int in concat should of course result in an empty DF with exactly the same columns and index names - and your code just fails. An empty DF just has no data in it, but the shape needs to be kept of course. And when I concat two DFs with different shapes, of course the resulting shape must be changed accordingly.

You can try this:
result = (df_treatment.copy() if df_no_treatment.empty else df_no_treatment.copy() if df_treatment.empty else pd.concat([df_treatment, df_no_treatment]).sort_index())


This is just the same as the code I put in the question - just in one line. This is error-prone (you might forget the "both empty" case) and cumbersome to write where previously a simple concat was sufficient. And also consider the case of more than 2 DFs please.

Well -there is no other option. They will should add an argument to pd.concat that enables empty dataframes
